# glmer in lme4, interpreting significant sum-coded interaction in the presence of non-significant pairwise comparisons

Tags: lme4-nlme, interaction, regression-coefficients, multiple-comparisons

This is my first question, so I apologize if I am leaving out information. If that's the case, I'll do my best to fix it.

I have two predictors of interest, sentence type (PO, DO) and condition (given-new, new-given) and their interaction, and the dependent variable is reaction time. I have analyzed these factors using `glmer` in lme4 with the factors dummy coded (the R default coding scheme). There are two co-variates included as well, 'trial number' and comp_correct. Varying slopes and intercepts for condition conditioned on participant ID and item are also included. The categorical variables are sum coded. The full model statement is:

```
glmer(Reaction_Time ~ Sentence_type*Condition + comp_correct + 
    Trial Number + 1 + (1|Participant_External_Session_ID) + 
    (1+Condition|Item), data=SPR_YA2_R4,family=Gamma(link="identity"),
     control =  glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

The output summary is:

[image: Summary of statistical output showing significant interaction]

There is a significant interaction sentence type by condition. However, when I run pairwise comparisons, neither sentence type differs significantly between levels of condition:

[image: Pairwise comparisons using emmeans, showing no significant difference for sentence type by levels of condition]

I am not sure how to interpret this. The presence of this interaction is theoretically consequential, but I don't know how to explain why this interaction is a reliable even when the pairwise comparisons are not significant.